# How to speed up apt-get update?

Tags: apt

`sudo apt-get update` is extremely slow (take serveral hours), how to speed it up ?
I already tried much solutions including forcing **IPv4**, editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`, choosing the "*best server*" in Software & Updates settings ... but in vain.
I have the same problem in both Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 (VMs).

Comment: Get a speedier internet connection. Disable IPv6 if your ISP don't support it. It is difficult to answer your question since you don't give any details on what `sudo apt-get update` uses it time at.

Comment: @SorenA - my internet connection is fast enough, I download packages using my browser without problem, this issue is just with `apt-get`.

Comment: Is a specific repository slow, or are all of them slow?

Comment: - All of them :(

Comment: Retrieving updates from the Internet is the first part of the process. After that, the download summary is given (something like "2773 kB retrieved in 1s (2331 kB/s)"). Are you saying that this is the part that takes hours?

Comment: Yes @Jos , It shows me just 1000 B/s

Comment: Try to download some files from the repository manually via wget:
e.g. wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Contents-amd64.gz
If it is as slow as apt-get, then you have a bandwidth problem, which can't be fixed by apt-get

Comment: `wget` works fine, the problem is just with `apt-get`

Comment: This fixed the problem, https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2477  It appears APT was using the main ubuntu archive mirror instead of an archive mirror that's geographically closer.

Answer (score 2):

Change the server location from the software update settings,
prefer your country server for the fast repository get requests,

And then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: didn't work for me